# RuntimeError: Unexpected ASGI message 'websocket.send', after sending 'websocket.close'

Tags: python, asynchronous, websocket, fastapi

- I am trying to build a chat server with two websocket endpoints. One for the room owners to create_room and second for others who wants to join the room.
- I have 'Room' and 'RoomManager' classes. Room has list of members, and other room info. where as 'RoomManager' helps in creating rooms and accepting people into the room.
- when a user tries to enter the room with room_id i am sending a request to the room_owner whether to add the member to the room. When user accepts I am adding the member to the list of members in the room.
- when a new user tries to enter a room and the owner accept it (by sending 'yes') I wanted to broadcast "xxxx has entered the room".
  When I try to broadcast it shows this error "RuntimeError: Unexpected ASGI message 'websocket.send', after sending 'websocket.close' ".
  This is the [link](https://github.com/nandu1336/spare-chats/tree/master/src) to repo. I heard of sending ping pong framesbut did not find docs to implement it.

**Files explanation in repo:**

- **app.py :** contains http and websocket endpoints
- **room_manager.py :** has Room and RoomManager classes.
- **connection_manger.py:** default connection manager provided by fastapi docs. Used to store temporary connections before user is part of any room.

This is the [link to the cmd log](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/3438).

Answer (score 2):

The error "RuntimeError: Unexpected ASGI message 'websocket.send', after sending 'websocket.close'" literally means that you are trying to send a message on a connection that was closed. From what I understand from your question you are keeping a list of users that are part of a room when a user enters the room and you are broadcasting this welcome message to all the other users of the room. But what if a user has disconnected or the underlying connection of a particular user s closed? In this case you'll get the above mentioned error.

What can solve this problem is you should always check for connection closed exception while reading/ writing messages on a connection and should mark the user disconnected if such exception occurs.

Comment: okay but what if I don't want the connection to be lost?

Comment: Websocket has operational messages to keep the underlying connection alive from ideal drops/ firewalls, etc. You can choose to do this. Alternatively you can implement your client side (users) to reconnect if they got disconnected.
It's always a good practice to handle disconnects rather than implementing the solution which assumes nothing will ever fail